# Limit including lower branch of Lambert function

Tags: inequality, lambert-w

I am trying to show that

$\frac{1}{2\left(1-e^x\right)}-\frac{1}{x}W_{-1}\left[\frac{x}{2\left(1-e^x\right)}\exp\left(\frac{x}{2\left(1-e^x\right)}\right)\right]\geq 1,$

for $x>0$, where $W_{-1}$ is the lower branch of the Lambert function. Do you have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Using Maple, this seems valid only for $x > x_0 \approx 0.404733$

Comment: That is strange. In Mathematica for $x=0.2$ I obtain 7.11 for the function value, which converges to 1 as $x\rightarrow \infty$. I updated the question though, I am looking for $x>0$ only.

Comment: Sorry, forget my comment. I missed the $\frac{1}{x}$ in front of $W_{-1}$. I can now reproduce your value for $x=0.2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above calculus shows that the limit is $=1$ indeed.

[image]
[image]

Moreover, numerical calculus shows that $f(x)$ is a decreasing function (graph below).

As a consequence : $\quad f(x)>1$

Of course, numerical calculus isn't a definitive proof. But it is very convincing.

[image]

NOTE :

What was done above is sufficient to prove that the limit is $1$ : this is only the main term of the asymptotic expansion. But it is not sufficient to give a correct expression for the next term. If we want a correct expression of $f(x)$ at infinity of $x$, more terms are needed in the asymptotic series of $t$ and $X$ and $W_{-1}(X)$.